# e.getX(); does not work accurately

Tags: java, mouseevent

So I have run into a problem where, when I read the mouse position and try to manipulate it everything goes to hell !

Here is the code for this disaster.

```
public class LoadScreen implements MouseListener{

    int x,y;
    public void begin(Graphics g, JPanel def) {
        def.addMouseListener(this);
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString("Welcome to FaivaCodex's Live Interaction Game Shell", 30, 200);
        Font font2=new Font("Triplex",Font.PLAIN, 17);
        g.setFont(font2);
        g.drawString("Enjoy making your game, for any more gameshells you would like to be availible send an email to flaivaflaves@gmail.com ",  30, 230);
        g.fillRect(x-5,y-5,x+10,y+10);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        x=arg0.getX();
        y=arg0.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

And there is an image of what it produces but I cant post images yet. What I want is 10*10 pixel box where the mouse is, but what I can tell you is....This rectangle is huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters for `fillRect(...)` are the coordinates `x`, `y` and the size `width` and `height`, which means that if `x = 100` and `y = 100` your code will product a 110x110 rectangle starting at x 100, y 100.

If you want to create a 10x10 rectangle starting at the mouse's pointer, use this:

```
g.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
```

Comment: Thnx.But need to know how to follow mouse.

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer  you will need a `MouseMotionListener` for that not a `MouseListener`

Answer (score 0):

```
g.fillRect(x-5,y-5,x+10,y+10);
```

`fillRect` takes [x,y,width and height as parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), so you'll need to make that

```
g.fillRect(x-5,y-5,10,10);
```

Comment: ahh, darn it my mistake.I even knew that jeez im tired.Thnx

Comment: but it doesnt follow the mouse

Comment: how do i get it to do that?

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer You'll probably need a MouseMotionListener, but I wouldn't be re-adding a listener each time begin is called